Simple loop through large xts gives fatal error
I'm trying to add a variable that keeps track of the all-time high of a time series. The below code doesn't work - R encounters a fatal error during the for loop. I don't quite understand what's wrong here.

Edit: Even stranger now. Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't.
library(quantmod)
GSPC_df <- getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE,
                      from = "1927-12-30")
GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH <- GSPC_df$GSPC.Close
for (i in (2:nrow(GSPC_df))){
  GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH[i] <- max(GSPC_df$GSPC.Close[i], GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH[i - 1])
}

And - if it works - it is much, much slower than the (maybe not so) equivalent operation on a regular dataframe:
library(quantmod)
GSPC_df <- as.data.frame(getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE,
                      from = "1927-12-30"))
GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH <- GSPC_df$GSPC.Close
for (i in (2:nrow(GSPC_df))){
  GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH[i] <- max(GSPC_df$GSPC.Close[i], GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH[i - 1])
}


And your error is?  And some sample data might be?  Also, "If I'm thinking of using a for loop in R, there's probably a better way" is a useful maxim.  I suspect this is a case in point: take a look at dplyr::lag.

@Limey The error is that RStudio sort of crashes. I've included the message above. The data used should be available to anybody. I'll have a look at dplyr::lag, but I would still be interested to learn why the above sometimes fails.

I would try GSPC_df$GSPC.ATH = cummax(GSPC_df$GSPC.Close), that should be faster than your loop by several orders of magnitude.

Use cummax as shown.  Returning zoo from getSymbols will improve the subsequent name processing but is otherwise similar to using xts.  We convert to xts at the end.  This last line is optional.
library(magrittr)
library(quantmod)

stock <- "^GSPC" %>%
  getSymbols(auto.assign = FALSE, return.class = "zoo") %>%
  na.omit %>%
  transform(ATH = cummax(Cl(.))) %>%
  as.xts   # optional


That's pretty sleek. It doesn't quite work if (the second instance of) 'stock' wasn't defined yet. And it misses the 'from', which in this case matters. But otherwise very helpful. Any idea what's the trouble with the code in de question?

Have fixed code.  The code in the question seems to work for me.  Are you using an old version of quantmod or R?

Both quantmod and R are fresh.

Try it without RStudio, just R.

6 OK out of 6 attempts! (Still super-slow though.)

The first one in the question, using R (without RStudio). Meanwhile I'm trying to figure out how to give the new variable the name ATH, because it (your version) gives GSPC.Close.1 now.

Have revised the solution again.  It seems that the naming problem goes away if we use zoo instead of xts so we added return.class="zoo" and then convert to xts at the end.
